# Как сравнить переменную со списком?

Tags: python

Есть 1 значение, и есть список в котором около 10 значений.
Как мне узнать есть ли оно в списке?

команда боту звучит по типу "добавить администратора"

```py
if (str(us_id)) in admin_id: #id юзера сравниваем со списком айдишников

    #если в списке айдишников есть ваш(значит что вы администратор и бот будет слушать вас)

                    
    admins = [] # записываем в список айди человека которого хотим добавить в администраторы
    with open('adm.py', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    
        old_data = f.read()
        new_data = old_data.replace(']',' ')
        f.close()
        admins.append(reply_us_id)
     
        with open('adm.py', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    
            f.write(new_data)
            f.close()
            admins.append(reply_us_id)
    
            admins = []
            with open('adm.py', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    
                f.write('\n"' + (str(reply_us_id)) + '",]')
                f.close()
                admins.append(reply_us_id)
                time.sleep(2)
```

проблема вот в чем, изначально в список занес свой айди дабы бот слушал мои команды, затем просто выдал админку другому человеку, и вот этого человека собственно он не слушает, его айди есть в списке он нормально записан перепроверил сто раз

список лежил в txt-шнике :

`admin_id = [""]`

Comment: для начала приведите код где не работает, потому что `in` должно работать. У вас точно список, а не словарь?

Comment: или не список, или разный тип сравниваемых данных

Comment: что у вас находится в `pt`   и `poop`?

Comment: `poop = ["12345" , "123456", "1234567"]`

`pt = 12345`

`if pt in poop:`

как-то так

Comment: строка с интом ну никак не будут не равны, хоть на экране могут выглядеть одинаково... попробуйте ```if str(pt) in poop: ```

Comment: так и пробовал, работает через раз

Comment: добавляйте весь код в вопрос, чтоб не гадать на кофейной

Comment: обновил вопрос.

Comment: У меня все работает

Comment: и как это может "не работать"? вы, случайно, под "узнать, есть ли оно в списке" не имеете ввиду "узнать, **есть ли оно в каждом из элементов списка**"?

Comment: если обновить этот список с помощью (добавив в него новое значение, и затем проверить его наличие в списке)

`with open('test.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:

                                f.write(new_data)`

то не работает, а сам список как раз таки в txt лежит

Comment: потому и нужно добавлять **весь код в вопрос**, чтоб понимать, что откуда у вас берется

Comment: хорошо, добавлю весь абсолютно, до последнего символа, а не конкретно проблемное место

Comment: обновил вопрос, добавил абсолютно весь код

Comment: у вас admin_id пустой поэтому всегда возвращается False

Comment: он не пустой, просто не палю айдишники с вк, там их два,

даже метод включил чтоб возвращал айди при обращении.

по итогу : в списке лежит айдишник другого человека, в методе мне его возвращает, сравниваю их - все правильно.

скрипт не может его в списке найти, вот так вот